# Change the src of an image when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the `src` of an image and once it was changed to remain like that over the whole website.

```
<img id="profile" src="profilePicture.jpg">
<input type="text" name="image" id="imgLink">
<button type="button" id="upload">Upload</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var link;
    $("#upload").click(function (){
        link = $("#imgLink").val();
        $("#profile").prop('src', link);
    });
    $("#profile").prop('src', link);   
  });
```

As you can see I tried to store the link of the image in a global variable( var link ) , change the `src` of the image inside the function and then change it once again outside so that the page loads the image when it's loaded.

Changing the `src` of the image works but once I refresh the page or go to another page and come back, the image is not changed any more.

How can I make it to remain changed over the whole website?

Comment: A global variable exists outside of the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: I'm new with jQuery, my problem is that the link variable has no value outsite the .click(function() {.. Because I tried to put a link to an image in the var link and then just change the src of the image and this works. But I need it to work when the link is provided via the input.

Comment: Use cookies to store the URL between page refreshes and page navigation. Or server side scripts would do the trick.

Comment: When you beg to not get down votes, usually that leads to down votes.

Comment: I'm not actually begging to not get downvotes, just trying really hard to find the answer to something I can;t figure out myself. I'm just asking the person who might want to downvote, the reason why he/she would do it so I will know in the future when I ask more question or maybe to be more explicit with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would do this on the serverside since a clientside solution only works on the one browser the user is using.

```
$(function () { 
    //read localstorage
    var link = localStorage.getItem("myImage") || ""; //change "" to default value
    $("#upload").click(function (){
        link = $("#imgLink").val();
        $("#profile").prop('src', link);
        localStorage.setItem("myImage", link); //set localstorage with new value. 
    });
    $("#profile").prop('src', link);   
});
```